# Seed URL for Apache Nutch Web Crawling

Tags: nutch

Apache Nutch recommends http://rdf.dmoz.org/rdf/content.rdf.u8.gz as seed URLs for web crawling. However, they have shut down the website. Is there any alternative seed URLs for web crawling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at http://commoncrawl.org. I think they offer a really comprehensive dataset.